# Percent of a bootstrap progress bar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have a sales goal i want to hit every quarter, say 100.

My progress bar is supposed to show what my pace is with sales so far in the qtr.

[image]

if im behind pace

[image]

Over pace

[image]

Heres the kicker, i cant think of a way to show the red mark as an accurate percentage of the green bar because its a percent of a percent. Bootstrap seems to only let me stack progress bars but i just want to show a percent of that progress bar as red or blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **box-shadow:inset** to create an inner border on the right side - inside the progress bar (you can use js to determine the colour and size required) without changing the overall outer dimension of the bar. I used a progress bar of 35% width and a box shadow of -13px and colour red. These can be calculated relative to your sales figures and amended accordingly.

Note for the sake of this - I used inline styling for the css rule - I would normally pull that out and have it in the external CSS, but I did it this way for this example.

[image: progress bard]

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 35%;  box-shadow:inset -13px 0px 0px red;">
  <span class="sr-only">35% Complete (success)</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thats a clever way to go about it!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Stacked progress bar may save you, check: [Stacked progress bar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked)